# Use off() directly in on() callback Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Let's say I have a one and done operation. Like deletes.

```
var q = ref.child('users').child(targetUserId).child('chat');
q.on('child_added', function(obj) {
  obj.ref().remove();

  //This works right?
  q.off();
});
```

Can I execute `off()` directly in the `on()` callback? I don't need to specify `eventType` correct?

Nothing else to clean up right?

[From the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html):
*Similarly, if no eventType or callback is specified, all callbacks for the reference will be removed.*

Comment: If you're turning it on and off again like that, you may consider using `once` instead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was trying to use `once()` on a slightly different version of the example above - `q.endAt(estimatedServerTimeMs-5000).once(...)` - but the `remove()` would only delete a single record (the first one in the matching set). Changing `once` to `on` would delete all of the matching records. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: When using `once` Firebase will only fire a single event. So in case of `child_added` it will only fire for a single child (no matter how many children match the query). For your original question that is precisely what you need. But indeed for the use-case in your comment, stick to `on('child_added'` and `off` it on the right condition or alternatively `once('value'` and then `forEach` over the children in the snapshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I execute `off()` directly in the `on()` callback?

Yes.

> I don't need to specify eventType correct?

Correct. As the docs state, if the `eventType` is omitted, all callbacks for the reference will be removed.

You can also just chain the `.off()` method like this rather than calling it inside of the callback:

```
var q = ref.child('users').child(targetUserId).child('chat');
q.on('child_added', function(obj) {
  obj.ref().remove();
}).off();
```

---

As [Frank van Puffelen suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266507/use-off-directly-in-on-callback-firebase#comment44889983_28266507) in the comments, you can also use the [`.once()` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) in order for the callback to only be executed once:

```
var q = ref.child('users').child(targetUserId).child('chat');
q.once('child_added', function(obj) {
  obj.ref().remove();
});
```

The benefit to this approach is that you don't have to worry about inadvertently removing other attached events.

Comment: I'm not positive that you can chain them. [.on() returns the callback function, not the `this` context ref](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html)